# @Autowired finding ambiguous dependencies and still works. How?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

Why is Spring not throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` where there are  ambiguous dependencies and more than one bean candidates found for autowiring using `@Autowired` annotation ?

I have this simple beans.xml that has two same beans with different ids `category` and `category1` and for some reason Spring 
picks the `category` bean for autowiring. I was under the impression that `@Autowired` annotation uses `byType` autowiring internally
and since here there are more than one matches found here Spring will throw `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception.

I am using spring version `3.2.13.RELEASE` here.

beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     .....   ">

        <context:annotation-config />

        <bean id="product" class="com.study.spring.Product">
            <property name="id" value="101"/>
            <property name="name" value="Apple iPhone"/>
            <property name="active" value="true"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="category1" class="com.study.spring.Category">
            <property name="id" value="202"/>
            <property name="name" value="Phone"/>
            <property name="active" value="true"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="category" class="com.study.spring.Category">
            <property name="id" value="201"/>
            <property name="name" value="Communications"/>
            <property name="active" value="true"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Product.java

```
package com.study.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean active;
    @Autowired
    private Category category;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes the `Category` object with the id `category` because it matches the name of the field. The old [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) explain this as:

> "For a fallback match, the bean name is considered as a default qualifier value."

The [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire) explains this a bit clearer. You have a "byName" autowiring situation here:

> Autowiring by property name. Spring looks for a bean with the same name as the property that needs to be autowired. For example, if a bean definition is set to autowire by name, and it contains a master property (that is, it has a setMaster(..) method), Spring looks for a bean definition named master, and uses it to set the property.

Comment: I was reading Spring in Action - 3rd Edition and this is an excerpt from the book that's confusing me. QUALIFYING AMBIGUOUS DEPENDENDENCIES - On the other hand, may be the problem’s not a lack of beans for Spring autowiring to choose from but it’s an abundance of (or at least two) beans, each of which is equally qualified to be wired into a property. For example, suppose you have two beans that implement Instrument. In that event, there’s no way for @Autowired to choose which one you really want. So, instead of guessing, a  NoSuchBeanDefinitionException will be thrown and wiring will fail.

Comment: Clearer now? Have you tried to rename the field to something else than `category` and see what happened then?

Comment: Yes, I understood. I renamed `category` to `category1` which resulted in an exception `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. So, in case of ambiguity Spring has a fallback mechanism which resolves the bean ambiguity `byName` autowiring feature otherwise `byType` is the default.